# WinCE 6.0: Customizing Control Panel (cplmain)

Tags: c++, windows-ce, platform-builder

i work on a Windows CE 6.0 Image and added a Audio driver to my Solution (my solution is based on a image without audio). Sound works fine but i dont know how i can add the standard Windows CE 6.0 Sound Settings dialog to the control panel.

MSDN says the following:
"The Windows CE Control Panel allows users to set a variety of system-wide properties, such as mouse sensitivity, network setup, and the desktop color scheme. You can select specific functionality to include in your Control Panel by specifying them in your Cesysgen.bat file."
Can anyone explain how this works exactly via Cesysgen.bat? In my project i cant find any entry for cplmain in my Cesysgen.bat.

Could it be that those standard Applets are integrated into the control panel automatically? (maybe with "getProcAddress()" when a specific driver is loaded?) - This idea comes from "cplmain.def", there is written:

```
EXPORTS
    CPlApplet

    ; These functions are exported for componentization
    ; We use GetProcAddress on ourselves to dynamically discover 
    ; what components we have
```

I found a quite good explanation from Andrew Pearson here:
http://www.itlisting.org/4-windows-ce-embedded/a57eef4103191b7a.aspx
but i tried a few different things an nothing worked! So this confuses me even more. The only statement there i really understand now is:

```
The control panel, unfortunately, is about the single most confusing thing 
to build in the whole tree.
```

Yes it is! Would be nice if anyone had an idea.

Kind regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

I've created custom control panel applets before, and to be honest, trying to modify the existing applet is about the worst thing you can try.  Generally what I do is just create a whole new applet, which is really just a DLL renamed to have a `.cpl` extension and that exports the [`CPlApplet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926276.aspx) entry point.

There's [an example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms914264.aspx) that shows the expected values the OS will pass in to get your icon, tell you to start and those types of things.

Basically just build your own applet as a completely separate project, then include it in the MODULES section of your BIB file.  Don't even mess with the existing train wreck of control panel code.

Comment: Hmm. The thing is that i dont want to include an own applet. The "CPLMAIN" contains code for an applet called "Sound & Volume Settings". But my image does not show this icon in the control panel. So would you suggest me to try to get the code for this applet out of cplmain and make an own applet from it? That also seems to be very complicated as the code is well integrated in cplmain.

Comment: Do you have audio included in your image?  IIRC, BSP_NOAUDIO might be what removes that icon, which would get turned off by including audio from the catalog (the entire build system is built on the concept of negative logic it would seem)

Comment: I included an audio driver in the image, yes. But as there was no driver released from the supplier of our processor in the bsp (freescales iMX35 does not support audio via AC97), i wrote an audio driver based on a driver for another platform. I didnt inlcude the driver in the catalogue so far. When i search the CPLMAIN sources for the BSP_NOAUDIO variable i get no hits. The variable is not defined in my solution. I will try to build the solution with "set BSP_NOAUDIO=0".

Comment: Setting BSP_NOAUDIO to zero may not work, some batch files or tools may just check if the variable is defined, not caring about the value. You can open a command prompt from the "Build\Open release directory" option in VS and use the set command to check the current environment. Check also your BSP batch file (same name as the bsp in the BSP root folder) since this is the usual place when such a variable will be set. I agree about Chris' comment on not trying to clone default CPL apps and writing a new one.